# biff exception: unrecognizedOLE

Tags: excel, exception

Just trying to read from an ordinary excel file which I craeted using microsoft excel starter 2010 and saved as an excel 97-2003 file because I originally thought the exception was due to the file format. Apparently this exception means there is something embedded in the file that cannot be read, but for the life of me I dont know how or why that is. It's just a simple excel file I typed out myself. The stacktrace is as follows:

```
[CDATA[jxl.read.biff.BiffException: Unable to recognize OLE stream
at jxl.read.biff.CompoundFile.<init>(CompoundFile.java:116)
at jxl.read.biff.File.<init>(File.java:127)
at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:221)
at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:198)
at test.ExcelClass.updateTestResultsSpreadsheet(ExcelClass.java:1707)
at test.Internal_TestSuite.afterSuite(Internal_Virgin_TestSuite.java:846)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:543)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:212)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:309)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:241)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1169)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1094)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1006)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:107)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:199)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:170)
]]>
```

I have used similar files without this exception being thrown. Any ideas?? Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I solved the problem by removing another MS excel starter 2010 (.xlsx) file I was using elsewhere in my testNG class and making it a .xls file. It appears the stacktrace was not pointing at the correct location of the problem? Or at least it didn't change when I removed the first file? Anyway it's fixed, the JExcel api isn't compatible with other excel formats.

Comment: Looks like you are using JExcelApi, an open source library.  The way open source works is giving you access to the source code so you can debug it and fix the problem.  And check back the fix so other users benefit.  Good luck and thanks for contributing.